# How to handle events for two separate buttons in one method?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have two UIButtons on my view, one for FM radio and one for AM radio.
When the FM button is pressed, I want to display the FM values for station name, frequency, and bandwidth values in their respective labels, and likewise for AM.

I had working code using a separate buttonClick method for each button but since the code was identical, I wanted to try to do it all inside the one method. This abomination is below!

Here is the code right now for the button press method.

```
    @IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: Any) {
        if buttonFM != nil {
            if myStation.isBandFM() == 1 {
            stationBand.text = "FM1"
            stationName.text = myStation.name //set top left label text to name property of myStation object
                stationFrequency.text = "\(myStation.frequency)"
            }
        } else if buttonAM != nil {
            if myStation.isBandFM() == 0 {
            stationBand.text = "AM1" //final exercise, part 1.
            stationName.text = myStationAM.name
            stationFrequency.text = "\(myStationAM.frequency)"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the entire view controller code:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var stationName: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var stationFrequency: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var stationBand: UILabel!

        @IBOutlet weak var buttonFM: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var buttonAM: UIButton!

        var myStation: RadioStation //FM station

        var myStationAM: RadioStation //AM station

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            myStation = RadioStation()  
            myStationAM = RadioStation()
            myStation.frequency = 104.7
            myStationAM.frequency = 800.2
            myStation.name = "FM1"
            myStationAM.name = "AM1"
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            stationName.text = nil 
        }

        @IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: Any) {
        if buttonFM != nil {
            if myStation.isBandFM() == 1 {
            stationBand.text = "FM1"
            stationName.text = myStation.name //set top left label text to name property of myStation object
                stationFrequency.text = "\(myStation.frequency)"
            }
        } else if buttonAM != nil {
            if myStation.isBandFM() == 0 {
            stationBand.text = "AM1" //final exercise, part 1.
            stationName.text = myStationAM.name
            stationFrequency.text = "\(myStationAM.frequency)"
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the class method:

```
class RadioStation: NSObject {

    var name: String
    var frequency: Double

    override init() {  //init class method to set default values.
        name = "Default"
        frequency = 100
    }

    static var minAMFFrequency: Double = 520.0
    static var maxAMFFrequency: Double = 1610.0
    static var minFMFFrequency: Double = 88.3
    static var maxFMFFrequency: Double = 107.9

    func isBandFM() -> Int {
        if frequency >= RadioStation.minFMFFrequency && frequency <= RadioStation.maxFMFFrequency {
            return 1 //FM
        } else  {
            return 0 //AM
        }

}
```

Comment: In your `@IBAction func buttonClick`, the `if` question is the wrong question. The question is: _who is `sender`?_

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out how to identify FM button vs AM button as the sender. Can I check by the text of the button? That doesn't sound good/like it would work though.

Comment: Downcast safely to UIButton and use `===`.

Comment: I tried `if buttonFM.isTouchInside == true` to identify the sender but this didn't work.

Comment: No I did, and I appreciate your help. I had just thought between your comments that a check for if the button was pressed would work. I don't fully understand downcasting or why it would work/be needed here. I tried `if sender === buttonFM as? UIButton` but getting error 'Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any' and 'UIButton?''.

Comment: That’s closer. In fact you could write `if (sender as! UIButton) === buttonFM`, but it would be better to downcast safely: `if let sender = sender as? UIButton, sender === buttonFM`

Comment: “if the button was pressed would work” You already know a button was pressed. If it hadn’t you wouldn’t be here. The question is which one. And the sender is the one. It is screaming Me Me Me. All you have to do is listen.

Comment: Sorry for delay. Yup this worked. Thank you for your help and keeping with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can't stop people from writing bad code. The reason this is bad code is it breaks [S][O]LID — Separation of concerns and also Open/Close. Now the button action is handling more than one concern.

Anyway, change your sender type from any to UIButton, then check the label title.

```
    @IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let button = sender.titleLabel?.text else {return}
        if button == buttonFM.title {
            if myStation.isBandFM() == 1 {
            stationBand.text = "FM1"
            stationName.text = myStation.name //set top left label text to name property of myStation object
                stationFrequency.text = "\(myStation.frequency)"
            }
        } else if button == buttonAM.title {
            if myStation.isBandFM() == 0 {
            stationBand.text = "AM1" //final exercise, part 1.
            stationName.text = myStationAM.name
            stationFrequency.text = "\(myStationAM.frequency)"
        }
    }
}
```

You've got to think about it like this. If you want to modify the functionality of one of the buttons in the future now you'll have to edit the buttonClick action under two separate circumstances.

If you really want to do this like this I would suggest doing some abstraction at least and creating two functions like so...

```
// Using some abstraction if you decide to make modification
// based on an action you wont need to touch this method anymore. 
// The changes would be made in their corresponding functions. 

    @IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: UIButton) {

        guard let button = sender.titleLabel?.text else {return}

        if button == buttonFM.title {
               buttonFMClick()
            }
        } else if button == buttonAM.title {
               buttonAMClick()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For`if sender.titleLabel!.text == buttonFM` you would still have the error 'Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String?' and 'UIButton' so this doesn't work and looks like that would need the downcasting method also, see Matt's comments above. I agree about the code not being optimal - but I'm just 150 pages into a beginner book and one has to start somewhere. Most of this is new to me and I will for sure take on board about creating two different functions for this. I did have two separate button IBAction/methods before but I wanted to try out putting them into one.

Comment: I'm going to endeavour to do this every day until I get good.

Comment: timman, try the modification I made above. Sorry I dont have an IDE im literally just sitting in a park on my phone.  I think it should work now, we are checking the button.title property against the sender.titlelabel.text

Comment: Still has the error: `Value of optional type 'UILabel?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'text' of wrapped base type 'UILabel'`

Comment: Try this, sorry no IDE.

Comment: Thank you. Just wondering - why would you not use downcasting method instead? Is there any reason you have a preference for your guard let statement here?

Comment: I feel like using the guard startment is cleaner than downcasting. Especially since we already know what the sender type is.